# ¿Cómo llamar de la capa BAL a mi formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, poo

estoy practicando con C# con programación por capas pero estoy algo perdido
En mi capa DAL tengo un metodo con parametros que otros metodos usaran, en este caso este es lo que tengo de metodo en mi capa DAL:

```
public void GenerarNombresArchivos(string name, string backPath, out string table, out string backName, out string zipName, out string rarName)
        {
            table = $"[{name}]";
            string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            backName = $"{backPath}\\filebak\\{name}_{fecha}.BAK";
            zipName = $"{backPath}\\{name}_{fecha}.ZIP";
            rarName = $"{backPath}\\{name}_{fecha}.rar";
        }
```

Teniendo en cuenta que name, backPath, table, backName, zipNmae y rarName no pertenecen a ningun campo en mi formulario (Yo lo entiendo que lo estoy manejando como variables globales).

Y así lo estoy manejando en mi capa BAL:

```
public void GenerarNombresArchivos(string name, string backPath, out string table, out string backName, out string zipName, out string rarName)
        {
            RespaldoDAL.GenerarNombresArchivos(name, backPath, out table, out backName, out zipName, out rarName);
        }
```

Lo que no entiendo bien es como manejarlo en el forms, por ejemplo tengo este boton donde meteré todo lo que tengo en el BAL para usarlos en el forms:

```
private void RespaldobarButtonItem_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
```

Pero no se como usarlo en el boton, esto es como lo he estado llamando pero no se si esta bien hecho, porque tengo parametros que como comente estan en los metodos (Yo lo entiendo como variables globales, que me corrijan si estoy mal) y hay otros campos igual en los metodos que si pertenecen al formulario, así es como lo estaba manejando en el forms llamando al BAL:

```
CLS_Respaldo_BAL RespaldoBAL = new CLS_Respaldo_BAL();
RespaldoBAL.GenerarNombresArchivos("name", "backPath")
```

No se si estoy trabajando correctamente o estoy haciendo algo mal, he probado de muchas formas llamando al BAL pero no funciona. cualquier ayuda se los agradecería.